# フローティングスタテックルートで設定した迂回経路が障害発生になった時、自動切り替わりしないです

Tags: windows

今学習している問題でわからないところがあり質問します。

１、２台のルータの（以下RT）それぞれにループバックインターフェイス０でIPアドレスを割り当てる
２、２台のRTはG0／0同士の線、G0／1同士の線の２本の線が通っている
　　　（どちらのGのインターフェイスも開放済み、IPアドレス割り当て済み）
３、ip routeでG0/1側にAD値の優先度の高い値を当てたスタテックルートを登録（AD値101）
４、ip routeでG0／0側にAD値の２番目の値を当てたフローティングスタテックルートを登録(AD値240)
５、RT１からもRT２からもお互いのループバックインターフェイスアドレスからお互いのループバックインターフェイスアドレスに向けたpingは通りました。

→ ここまでは順調にいったのですが問題がここからで、

６、「ここで故意的に障害を発生させて迂回経路への自動切り替えになるようにする」というお題があります。
７、RT1のG0／1をシャットダウンにしました。（片方のシャットダウンだけでいいそうなので）
８、するとシャットダウンしたRT1の方のルーティングテーブルの「S」は迂回経路に登録したAD値のものに自動切り替わりしており、pingも出来ました。
９、RT2の方を確認するとルーティングテーブルはそのままで、pingも届きませんでした。

？　→　色々と調べましたが、この場合どうすれば良いのでしょうか？
　　調べるとslaやobject trackなどが出てきましたがそれをするのでしょうか？
　（RT2のG0／1もシャットダウンすれば自動切り替わりになるのですが送信先のインターフェイスがシャットダウン等障害発生の時の対処法として知りたいです。）

？　→ どちらのルーティングテーブルも直接接続となる自分自身のインターフェイスのアドレスが/24のサブネットで設定しているのに表示が/32になります。これはそれで大丈夫なのでしょうか？

※ちなみにスタテックルーティングの所なので、ダイナミックルーティングはしていない前提です

どなたかわかる方いらっしゃいましたらご解答お願い致します。

Comment: 「windows」のタグを付けていますが、二台のルーターはWindowsのPCと言うことでしょうか？Windowsでは無いのであれば、ルーターが何か明記した上で、適切なタグに変更してください。

Answer (score 0):

> ７、RT1のG0／1をシャットダウンにしました。（片方のシャットダウンだけでいいそうなので）
> ８、するとシャットダウンしたRT1の方のルーティングテーブルの「S」は迂回経路に登録したAD値のものに自動切り替わりしており、pingも出来ました。
> ９、RT2の方を確認するとルーティングテーブルはそのままで、pingも届きませんでした。

RT1のインターフェースをシャットダウンすることでRT2がリンクダウンすることを期待しているように見えますが、機種にもよりますがインターフェースをシャットダウンしても物理インターフェースは停止しないのが一般的だと思います。RT1のインターフェースをシャットダウンしてもRT2には影響しません。よってルーティングテーブルもそのままです。

インターフェースが停止しない故障モードでは冗長経路が発動しないので、スタティックルーティングベースのフローティングスタティックは一般的ではないです。
ダイナミックルーティングをベースにして、経路情報が消えたことを契機にスタティックルートを浮かび上がらせるのが一般的な手法です。